# Triggering a method when a row in a Table View is edited

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is there a way to trigger a method (or a method its self which is triggered) when a Row in a is edited, more specifically, when text in a row is edited or when something changes in the Table View (e.g Row Added/Removed)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several.  You could use a data source.  You could using bindings. You might even go the subclassing route, but that is very rare, indeed.

I would suggest you start here:

[TableView Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000026)

Actually, given your other questions and the responses, I would suggest you start here:

[Cocoa Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: I see, there are some delegate notifications for Selection Did Change and Column Did Move or Resize. But not one specifically for when a row is edited.

Comment: You need to focus on the conceptual guides for Cooca, not on class documentation.  Cocoa implements particular patterns pervasively. In this case, you are likely going to want to read about NSControls and NSTextFields, and the editing process therein.